# Changing the Value of a MySQL ENUM Value, Throughout a Table

Tags: mysql, database-design, enums

I'm wondering if it is possible to change an `ENUM` value throughout a table, so that in all the rows where said `ENUM` value is represented, the change is made as well.

Comment: Use an update statement? `UPDATE table1 SET enum1 = 'male' WHERE enum1 = 'female'`

Comment: @Johan - And that wouldn't cause any problems? I'm guessing it would have to be done before the use of `ALTER` to change the `ENUM` value itself. But would it be allowed? I'm wondering because I thought that only specified values were allowed to be chosen in an enum column? And if the new value hasn't be specified yet...

Comment: Do an alter first and then the update, you cannot set an enum to a value that has not been set in the `create table`/`alter table` statement.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to change the value of an enum:

Suppose your old enum was:

```
ENUM('English', 'Spanish', 'Frenchdghgshd', 'Chinese', 'German', 'Japanese')
```

To change that use:

```
--  Add a new enum value
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE `fieldname` `fieldname` ENUM   
('English', 'Spanish', 'Frenchdghgshd', 'Chinese', 'German', 'Japanese', 'French');
-- Update the table to change all the values around.
UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = 'French' WHERE fieldname = 'Frenchdghgshd';
-- Remove the wrong enum from the definition
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE `fieldname` `fieldname` ENUM   
('English', 'Spanish', 'Chinese', 'German', 'Japanese', 'French');
```

MySQL will probably go through all the rows in your table trying to update stuff, I've heard stories of a planned optimization around that, but I'm not sure if that actually happened.

Comment: So you think MySQL will automatically go through the database and make any changes needed? I was thinking another method would be to use `ALTER` to *add* the new `ENUM` value to the set, then use `UPDATE` to replace any instances in the table of the old value, with the new value. Then finally, use `ALTER` to delete the old `ENUM` value. Do you think that would work?

Comment: An enum does not really store a string in the field it just uses the smallest integer that will hold the values in the enum, usually tinyint. If you change the strings in an enum mysql often time does not have to do anything to the row

Comment: so it just associates it via an integer?

Comment: Yep, although if you change the order of the enum, MySQL will also go in all the rows and rearrange the values in the fields. So that if you had enum('yes','no') and you `alter table t1 change enum1 enum1 enum ('no','yes')` all the no's and yes'es will stay the same.

Comment: Sorry, -1, this doesn't work. You *do* have to do what @stefmikhail said, namely, `ALTER TABLE` and *add* new `ENUM` values, `UPDATE` and  replace the old with the new, and `ALTER TABLE` again to remove the old enum values. @Johan maybe your example worked because `Frenchdghgshd` starts with `French`, but if you were changing `French` to `Française` you'd need two `ALTER TABLE`s and an `UPDATE` in between.

Comment: @Josh, Updated the answer, to reflect your input, thanks for that.

Comment: Usually, for compatibility using indexes (query for example: `SELECT * FROM \`tablename\` WHERE \`fieldname\` = 3`) last query must be replaced by
`ALTER TABLE \`tablename\` CHANGE \`fieldname\` \`fieldname\` ENUM
('English', 'Spanish', 'French', 'Chinese', 'German', 'Japanese');`